# Install python package via Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I tried to install two package (orange3 and orange3-Associate) for python via jupyter notebook by running:

```
!pip install orange3
!pip install orange3-Associate
```

II can import and use the packages via the jupyter notebook however in anaconda navigator environments I can not see any of these packages while I have all other libraries like numpy, sklearn, etc. Is it a problem or an issue?

Comment: `!pip -V` what result printed?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on [this blog](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/#How-to-use-Pip-from-the-Jupyter-Notebook) (update: Wayne notes in a comment below that the blog is outdated and points to [this Q&A](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) instead). Importantly, you should differentiate between `conda` and `pip`.

As you mention anaconda, you probably should use `conda` to install:

```py
# Install a conda package in the current Jupyter kernel
%conda install <dependency_name>
```

Alternatively, if you need to use `pip`:

```py
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
%pip install <python_package_name>
```

Comment: Great, thank you Wayne, I did not know that! I have updated my answer accordingly.